# error browser prevent my form - click submit button in ajax's success

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I have a problem about browser block my submit form (submit in new tab) when i click submit button in ajax's success.

First: i used ajax to get my text translate into chinese and put the result to text field of this form. In Ajax's success function, i put $("my submit button").click(). then my form is not submit because browser block it :

Here is my form:

```
  <?php 
    $catnews = CatNews::model()->findAll();
    echo CHtml::beginForm(['site/timkiemtaobao'], 'post', ['target' => '_blank']) . CHtml::textField('txtkeyword', '', ['placeholder' => 'Nhập theo sản phẩm, danh mục, hay nhãn hiệu tìm kiếm', 'class' => 'xx'])
        . CHtml::link('<img src="images/source/search.png">', 'javascript:void(0)', ['class' => 'btntim', 'id' => 'btntimkiem'])
        . CHtml::dropDownList('search', '', CHtml::listData($catnews, 'id', 'name'), ['class' => 'searchdrop']) ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php echo CHtml::textField('stringtimkiem', "", ['class' => 'hidden']) . CHtml::button('1', ['class' => 'hidden', 'id' => 'subbtn']) . CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

And here is my js:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btntimkiem', function() { // this for translate to chinese
  if ($("#txtkeyword").val() != '') {
    var c = $("#txtkeyword").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=myapikey",
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: {
        text: c,
        lang: "vi-zh"
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#txtkeyword").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#btntimkiem").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.text[0]);
        $("#stringtimkiem").val(data.text[0]);
        $("#subbtn").attr('type', 'submit').click().removeAttr('type');

      }
    });
    $("#txtkeyword").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#btntimkiem").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

So i'm very tired, because i have tried to fix it for 2 days but nothing is fixed.
i looking forward to your help. thank so much.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to prevent the submit button from submitting the form, or is it a problem that the submit button isn't submitting the form?

Comment: If you want to prevent the form from submitting, put `return false` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Barmar sorry about my English not good, my form submit and chrome block it like a popup, i want chome not block it

Comment: You can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151051/popup-a-new-window-in-an-ajax-success-callback-when-popup-blocker-is-on

Comment: @Barmar thank you :( so, do you know any way to get Json result from https. because if i can get json result without using ajax, i can submit form without blocking :( thanks you so much

Comment: Why don't you have the server script call the translate API, instead of doing it in Javascript?

Comment: @Barmar tks, let me try this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I expect that neither your handler nor your ajax is even being executed and the form is executing as a normal form. You can check this by adding in a `console.log` statement and checking for network activity in the browser's developer tools.

You need to give the form an `id`, something like:

```
CHtml::beginForm(['site/timkiemtaobao'], 'post', ['id' => 'btntimkiem'])
```

Comment: really, i will try

Comment: because, if i don't submit in blank (this submit is to foward to chinese web with keyword chinese - what i translate to send). if i submit normal, noproblem happend :( but, submit in newtab is blocked

Comment: Are you saying that you want to both submit the form and make an ajax call? Usually people do one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If it occurs in a new tab, try to place your code to $(document).ready();
I strongly recommend you not to use async false flag. Do it async, then

```
complete: $("#txtkeyword").removeAttr('disabled');
$("#btntimkiem").removeAttr('disabled');
```